# Vertically centered a rotate text

Tags: css, rotation, center

I tried the solutions in the previous questions, but none was successful.
I've 2 dynamic text that need to be rotated and centered into their content div (left and right).
All the solution that I tried doesn't work

Here's the code:

```css
#sideLeft span,
#sideRight span {
bottom: 50%;
display: block;
line-height: 0em;
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
top: 50%;
white-space:nowrap;
width: 100%;
}

#sideLeft span {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

#sideRight span {
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
transform: rotate(90deg);
}

#sideLeft,
#sideRight {
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 18%;
}

#sideLeft {
left: 0;
}

#sideRight {
right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="sideLeft"><span>Left text lorem ipsum sit amet</div>
<div id="sideRight"><span>Right text pellentesque lectus erat, condimentum quis sem vitae, facilisis </span></div>
```

Please, could you help me?

Thanks in advance :)

br0k3n

Comment: post the relevant html

Comment: Actuallly your code works http://jsfiddle.net/v85wgutw/ ... the problem is the last CSS styles with ID `thmlvSideLeft` must be just `sideLeft` and for right too

Comment: Hi, you're right, but as you can see the 2 text aren't vertically centered :(

Comment: You mean like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/v85wgutw/3/

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D unfortunatelly, as you can see the right and left text aren't correctly centered, but the first is quite near the to of the page and the second one near the bottom.

Comment: @DanielPinzon is correct, this does work and the text is vertically centered. The divs are rotated 90deg, perhaps you don't mean the actual vertical, but horizontal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center something (*since you use transforms*) you can `translate` it to `-50%` in both directions, after positioning it to the center of its container.

Also you should set the transform origin to be at the center of the element.

So this should fix it

```
#sideLeft span, #sideRight span {
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    white-space:nowrap;

    -webkit-transform-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -0-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    transform-origin:50% 50%;
}
#sideLeft span {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-90deg);
}
#sideRight span {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/uwLdox77/